# Scheduling QGIS Processing Jobs

Tags: python, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks, qgis

I'm trying to write a stand-alone QGIS Python script to be run by a scheduled task overnight and I'me getting stuck at the very beginning, when importing the processing module - the error I get states: "No module named processing.core.Processing". I've searched the internet for a solution, but  can't seem to find anything to make it work. Below is what I'm trying to run:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *


# Initialize QGIS Application
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:\Users\andreeam.popa\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

print 'Hello QGIS!'
```

and this is the batch file to launch the above:

```
REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
REM Gdal Setup
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal\
REM Python Setup
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

REM Launch python job
python X:\FunGis\Workspaces\Andreea\MyScripts\QGIS_Scripts\test.py
pause"
```

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem now solved. I had to change the sys.path.append to `c:\\Program Files\\QGIS Wien\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins` rather than `c:\\Users\\username\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins`